# Poor Mapbox GL JS performance compared to old Mapbox.js

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm in the process of rewriting route-planning web app from `Mapbox.js` to `Mapbox GL JS` library.

With all the features almost implemented, it's borderline unusable due to lags, non-smooth animations and general sluggishness of the **map layer**.

Now, it's entirely possible I'm using the API wrong. I made a quick comparison and published it here:

https://petrnagy.github.io/index.html#automove=no

Notice the old `Mapbox.js` (left) is much smoother than the new `Mapbox GL JS` (right).

You can see the difference more clearly here where both maps are moving and zooming:

https://petrnagy.github.io/index.html#automove=yes

This is just a basic example. The app itself also features:

- Dynamically styled routes (traffic, air quality, elevation)
- Rich UI which overlays the map
- Additional layers (eg. bicycle lanes, POIs, air quality)

With all there features, Mapbox GL JS is pretty much unusable. Unlike the old Mapbox.js, which is smooth.

Any advice for optimizing the performance appreciated!

Comment: Honestly, I can't see what you're complaining about. Maybe specific to your OS and browser? Perhaps record a video? It's true that Mapbox-GL-JS takes longer to zoom in, but you can tweak that if you don't like it. But your assertion that Mapbox-GL-JS is "borderline unusable" as a whole is, um, borderline ridiculous.

Comment: @SteveBennett Not complaining, looking for advice (as I wrote in the question) - did you read it? Tried multiple browsers and OS. No need for a video - I literally provided side-by-side demo where you can see the FPS difference even with tiny amount of content. It only gets worse with more layers. My point is the newer library is significantly slower than the old one, which is really strange and I'm looking for the bottleneck.

Comment: My experience with "performance" complaints is that what is obviously "bad performance" to one person is actually very subjective. Which is why I'm asking for you to be more specific (and objective) about exactly what issues you want help with.

Comment: @SteveBennett All questions are intrinsically subjective because they're based upon current understanding and perception of the world around us. What's 2+2? Be careful of how you answer, because at the center of a black hole it could be infinite. You're not arguing for better questions, you're arguing that no one should ask questions, because doing so always leads to subjective answers.

Comment: Jeepers. I'm trying to help you. As I said, I couldn't tell from looking at the demo what performance issue you're concerned about. Neither side stands out as better or worse. So I'm asking for you to be specific. I'm not sure how you think that attacking me will further your progress.

Comment: @SteveBennett I'm not attacking you in any way, despite your snarky and unhelpful comments.

Comment: Differences I observed at the demo links from the OP: 1) .js lets me see individual tiles appearing (replacing blank/white) when zooming or moving. 2) GL looks like a single, large image; I can't ever see a missing tile getting filled in. 3) .js performance seems more responsive/immediate. 4) GL performance feels like smooth-scroll with inertia or hysteresis.  OVERALL: I prefer the quick response of .js, AND the tile-less appearance of GL. But I hate the hysteresis in GL.

Comment: Here's a video I just captured of the automove demo from the OP that shows what I'm talking about. It's using automove instead of mouse control, so maybe the hysteresis is a part of the automove implementation and not a "real" issue?  https://monosnap.com/file/FKcK4NqfmkaVdd8jyhKjZVUfDAvRGr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's important to note that the older Mapbox.js library was serving raster tiles, which get rendered server side, where the more modern Mapbox GL JS is vector based and rendered client side. Due to the nature of raster vs. vector is why you might see this "dip" in performance, if you are looking strictly at FPS, because your machine may be struggling.

Mapbox.js, like other traditional JavaScript map libraries, used the basemap-overlay mapping convention. The basemap (or baselayer) is a raster tile layer that is served already rendered from the server and overlays are often vector data that sits on top of the basemap.

Mapbox GL JS has no distinction between baselayers and overlay layers, and uses mostly vector tiles. This means that map details like labels and icons and elements like streets and buildings can be modified with JavaScript, like overlays in earlier mapping libraries. Each layer provides rules about how the renderer should draw certain data in the browser, and the renderer uses these layers to draw the map on the screen.

You can read more about the difference here: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/web-apps/

There are also some great guides on [improving performance of Mapbox GL JS maps](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/mapbox-gl-js-performance/) and [working with large GeoJSON sources in Mapbox GL JS](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/working-with-large-geojson-data/)